# How to inject Middleware handler into Azure Function startup class, Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I want to add middleware exception handler into my Azure Function App.
I have registered Startup class in the app, with method overrides:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]

public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder){
 //my staff
}
```

and

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder){
 // builder.Services.....
}
```

I want to add the Middleware like in asp.net web app (using IApplicationBuilder app) but I can't add it to the project.

Is there any way to do it with Azure Functions app?

I didn't find a wait to do it

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an `Isolated process` Azure Function you can do it exactly as you would in an `Asp Web App`. See the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware).

In an `In process` Azure Function you don't have control of the start-up of the app and therefore there is no way to add Middleware. [This](https://www.bydutchies.com/blog/alternative-to-middleware-for-azure-functions) post shows an alternative way.